# Как удалить пробел из списка CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть несколько списков, в них есть пустые значения - `''`. Как их убрать? Вот мои списки:

```
['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email']
['Усольцев Олег Валентинович', '', '', 'ФНС', 'главный специалист – эксперт отдела взаимодействия с федеральными органами власти Управления налогообложения имущества и доходов физических лиц', '+7 (495) 913-04-78', 'opendata@nalog.ru']
['Мартиняхин Виталий Геннадьевич', '', '', 'ФНС', '', '+74959130037', '']
['Наркаев', 'Вячеслав Рифхатович', '', 'ФНС', '', '8 495-913-0168', '']
['Мартиняхин', 'Виталий', 'Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', 'cоветник отдела Интернет проектов Управления информационных технологий', '', '', '']
['Лукина Ольга Владимировна', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926', 'Olga.Lukina@minfin.ru']
['Паньшин Алексей Владимирович', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '8(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru']
['Лагунцов Иван Алексеевич', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)', '']
['Лагунцов Иван', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru']
```

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет смысла без примера результата, который вы хотите получить. CSV файл это табличные данные со строгим числом столбцов. Если удалить некоторые значения в разных строках - становится непонятно к какому столбцу относятся оставшиеся значения. В общем без примера желаемого результата или детального описания того, что вы хотите получить - этот вопрос не имеет смысла и не несет никакой пользы сообществу SO.

Answer (score 1):

Убрать то не проблема:

```
data = [
['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email'],
['Усольцев Олег Валентинович', '', '', 'ФНС', 'главный специалист – эксперт отдела взаимодействия с федеральными органами власти Управления налогообложения имущества и доходов физических лиц', '+7 (495) 913-04-78', 'opendata@nalog.ru'],
['Мартиняхин Виталий Геннадьевич', '', '', 'ФНС', '', '+74959130037', ''],
['Наркаев', 'Вячеслав Рифхатович', '', 'ФНС', '', '8 495-913-0168', ''],
['Мартиняхин', 'Виталий', 'Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', 'cоветник отдела Интернет проектов Управления информационных технологий', '', '', ''],
['Лукина Ольга Владимировна', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926', 'Olga.Lukina@minfin.ru'],
['Паньшин Алексей Владимирович', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '8(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru'],
['Лагунцов Иван Алексеевич', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)', ''],
['Лагунцов Иван', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru'],
]

new_data = [list(filter(None, item)) for item in data]
print(*new_data, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email']
['Усольцев Олег Валентинович', 'ФНС', 'главный специалист – эксперт отдела взаимодействия с федеральными органами власти Управления налогообложения имущества и доходов физических лиц', '+7 (495) 913-04-78', 'opendata@nalog.ru']
['Мартиняхин Виталий Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', '+74959130037']
['Наркаев', 'Вячеслав Рифхатович', 'ФНС', '8 495-913-0168']
['Мартиняхин', 'Виталий', 'Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', 'cоветник отдела Интернет проектов Управления информационных технологий']
['Лукина Ольга Владимировна', 'Минфин', '+7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926', 'Olga.Lukina@minfin.ru']
['Паньшин Алексей Владимирович', 'Минфин', '8(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru']
['Лагунцов Иван Алексеевич', 'Минфин', '+7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)']
['Лагунцов Иван', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru']
```

Только ведь по факту это таблица, и когда вы убираете из неё пустые ячейки вы перестаёте понимать, какие данные к какому столбцу у вас относятся.

Если убрать из пятой строки лишний элемент (везде 7 полей, а там 8), можно применить `Pandas` и получить табличку. с которой дальше и работать:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email'],
['Усольцев Олег Валентинович', '', '', 'ФНС', 'главный специалист – эксперт отдела взаимодействия с федеральными органами власти Управления налогообложения имущества и доходов физических лиц', '+7 (495) 913-04-78', 'opendata@nalog.ru'],
['Мартиняхин Виталий Геннадьевич', '', '', 'ФНС', '', '+74959130037', ''],
['Наркаев', 'Вячеслав Рифхатович', '', 'ФНС', '', '8 495-913-0168', ''],
['Мартиняхин', 'Виталий', 'Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', 'cоветник отдела Интернет проектов Управления информационных технологий', '', ''],
['Лукина Ольга Владимировна', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926', 'Olga.Lukina@minfin.ru'],
['Паньшин Алексей Владимирович', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '8(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru'],
['Лагунцов Иван Алексеевич', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)', ''],
['Лагунцов Иван', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df['phone'])
```

Вывод:

```
0                +7 (495) 913-04-78
1                      +74959130037
2                    8 495-913-0168
3                                  
4      +7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926
5                   8(495)748-49-73
6    +7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)
7                                  
Name: phone, dtype: object
```

Для примера я вывел все телефоны из таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Заметьте, что если вы сделаете просто `список.remove('')`, то `remove` не сработает. Значит будем работать не с этим, а с новым списком и выводить его.

```
data = [
['lastname', 'firstname', 'surname', 'organization', 'position', 'phone', 'email'],
['Усольцев Олег Валентинович', '', '', 'ФНС', 'главный специалист – эксперт отдела взаимодействия с федеральными органами власти Управления налогообложения имущества и доходов физических лиц', '+7 (495) 913-04-78', 'opendata@nalog.ru'],
['Мартиняхин Виталий Геннадьевич', '', '', 'ФНС', '', '+74959130037', ''],
['Наркаев', 'Вячеслав Рифхатович', '', 'ФНС', '', '8 495-913-0168', ''],
['Мартиняхин', 'Виталий', 'Геннадьевич', 'ФНС', 'cоветник отдела Интернет проектов Управления информационных технологий', '', '', ''],
['Лукина Ольга Владимировна', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 983-36-99 доб. 2926', 'Olga.Lukina@minfin.ru'],
['Паньшин Алексей Владимирович', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '8(495)748-49-73', '1248@minfin.ru'],
['Лагунцов Иван Алексеевич', '', '', 'Минфин', '', '+7 (495) 913-11-11 (доб. 0792)', ''],
['Лагунцов Иван', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ivan.Laguntcov@minfin.ru']
]
super_data = [x for i in data for x in i  if x ]
print(super_data)
```

Сначала поймём, что булев тип пустой строки (`''`) - `False`. Это нам и поможет.

Мы идём по элементам списка `data`. Затем проверяем тип каждого элемента вложенных списков. Если это `True` - добавляем в новый список, иначе нет.

Также моя программа удобна тем, что может удалять не только элементы `''`, но и `False`, `None`, `0` и т.д.

Помог ответ?